# Handle network connection

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic 2 app, and I need to know if there is internet connection (in general, any type) and it's not working.

If I do:

```
if (Network.connection) {
   this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.hasSession = true;
        } else {
            this.hasSession = false;
        }
    });
} else {
  // Go to home
}
```

The docs says to use `Network.type` but the editor says this property doesn't exist, and with `Network.connection` (whose description says it returns a string with the internet type) always returns `undefined`.

EDIT:

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any;

@Component({
    ......
})
export class .... {

    constructor(....) {}

    ionViewDidLoad(): void {

        this.retrieveAllPractises();
    }

    public retrieveAllPractises(): void {

        let networkState = navigator.connection.type;
        let isOnline = networkState != Connection.NONE;

        this.showLoading();

        if (isOnline) {

            firebase.database().ref('/audios').once('value')
                .then((snapshot) => {

                    let retrievedArray = snapshot.val();

                    for (let entry of retrievedArray) {

                        let practise: Practise = {
                            id: entry.id,
                            img: '',
                            children : entry.children,
                            name : entry.name,
                            new :  entry.new,
                            permission : entry.permission,
                            type : entry.type
                        };
                        practise.img = this.practiseImg(practise);
                        this.practises.push(practise);
                    }

                    this.addDownloadItem();
                    this.hideLoading();
                });

        } else {

            this.addDownloadItem();
            this.hideLoading();
            this.showOfflineStatusMsg();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code:

- Console throws me: Unused import: 'Network' L10: import { Network } from 'ionic-native';
- Browser console: ionViewWillEnter error: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: Why not just make the request you were planning to, and handle its failure if that happens?

Comment: Because I'm using firebase.auth() observable. Never fail. I will edit my post with the code

Answer (score 0):

Within your component/service, above class definition add:

```
declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any;
```

Which than lets you do the following:

```
let networkState = navigator.connection.type;
let isOnline = networkState != Connection.NONE;
```

**EDIT**

In order to use to above, you should also install the following cordova plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information --save
```

Comment: What does Connection.NONE returns? It should not be: let isOffline = Connection.NONE; ?

Comment: Connection.NONE means that the type of internet connection is neither WIFI, 3G or any other internet connection, which means that if the condition I wrote is TRUE, the device is connected to the internet, and if FALSE the device is offline.

Comment: Yes sorry, I tried it, and console throws me: Unused import: 'Network' 

      L10:  import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

Comment: And in browser console: ionViewWillEnter error: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: @IvanLencina your'e right, I forgot to mention something..editing

Comment: I was already installed this plugin, but without the --save flag. Can that be the problem?

Comment: No, it cannot be. can you please add your code to the question? (the new code, please share as much as possbile)

Comment: what version of Ionic do you use?

Comment: Sorry for the later response... I'm using Ionic  v2.1.14

Comment: Well, just came to my mind - how are you testing your code? are you running it on the browser or on a device?

Answer (score 0):

For `Network.type` to work properly your `ionic-native`version must be higher than 2.2.12, then you can use

```
if (Network.type == 'NONE') {
  //some code
} else {
 // Go to home
}
```

You can also check the Network plugin Docs in Ionic to see what connection types you can compare, like 4g, 3g, wifi, 2g, ethernet, etc.
If you want, you can too create a `Network.onDisconnect().subscribe()` to watch if the user gets disconnected so you can send him to the home page.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Network.type is deprecated, now is: Network.connection. But if I do: console.log(Network.connection);

It throws me an object without properties

Comment: If i do: if (Network.type != 'NONE')  , it goes always for the true way

Comment: if you have a connection yes, it'll always be true. Even if you disconnect from the internet and run the app it goes for true?

Comment: Yes, if i haven't got connection, it be true :/